# Excel Date Value 5 Months, 2 Weeks, or 3 Years - Need Less than 1 Yyear

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a date modified column and cell values like 5 months, 2 weeks, 3 years or 2 days.

How can I add logic in another column that would say "Yes" or "No" if the value is less than one year?

Comment: `=IF(A2<EDATE(TODAY(),-12),"YES","NO")`

Comment: @VBAPete I thought OP has strings, not dates

Comment: @CallumDA I think you are right.

Comment: @User2867778 Can you please share a data sample? Will there be entries like 100 months and 0.5 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you have cell values like this in, say, `A1:A4`

```
5 months
2 weeks
3 years
2 days
```

Then simply

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("year",A1)),"Yes","No")
```

Returns `Yes` if the value is less than a year, `No` otherwise

Comment: You're too quick, it says I can't mark as answered for 5 min lol

Comment: What would happen with 13 months?

Comment: It would say "yes", I.e. Less than a year - but given the (very limited) data OP provided I assumed that case wouldn't occur (perhaps as "1 year and 1 month" instead)